# Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, fastapi, data-mining

I am working on a classification model in which I use the logistic regression algorithm. I got as result: Prediction LR": "['AnxiousPersonalityDisorder']". Now I need to calculate the probability of this result and I have a lot of problem.
here is the code if anyone has an idea of the source of the problem

```
# code in colab notebook
x = df.text.values.tolist()
y = df.label.values.tolist()

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
data1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(x)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data1, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=32,stratify=y)
#Training model
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=40)
lr.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred_train = lr.predict(x_train)
y_pred_test = lr.predict(x_test)
```

i use fastapi for the deployment

````
class EmotionAdoPrediction():
    def __init__(self):
        # Note: for model_path you should make full path (see docker volume)
        self.vector = load("C:/Users/aabid/PycharmProjects/emotion-detection-multilabels/model1/Lrvector.joblib")
        self.model = load("C:/Users/aabid/PycharmProjects/emotion-detection-multilabels/model1/LRClassifier.joblib")
        self.classes_names = {0: ["angry"], 1: ["joy"], 2: ["sadness"], 3: ["fear"]}
        return

 def predict(self, text):
        text = self.data_cleaning(text)
        text_clean = self.standardization(text)
        probs = self.model.predict([[text_clean]])[:, 1]
        proba = np.max(probs[0])
        class_ind = np.argmax(probs[0])

        return self.classes_names[class_ind], proba```
````

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use the [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) package for logistic regression. If this is the case than you can calculate the probability of the result. The `LogisticRegression` class contains the `predict_log_proba(X)` and the `predict_proba(X)` function.

According to the documentation:

- `predict_log_proba(X)`: *Predict logarithm of probability estimates.*
- `predict_proba(X)`: *For a multi_class problem, if multi_class is set to be “multinomial” the softmax function is used to find the predicted probability of each class.*

Use the `predict_proba` function, because you have a multi class problem.

```
y_prob = lr.predict_proba(x_test)
```

EDIT: Also encode your labels from categorical values to  numerical values. Use `pandas.get_dummies` to convert the categorical value.

Comment: yes I know, but when I use the same function: "predict_proba" in the deployment with fastapi I got this problem, I don't know how I can fix it                                                       `def predict(self, text):
        text = self.data_cleaning(text)
        text_clean = self.standardization(text)
        probs = self.model.predict_proba([[text_clean]])
        proba = np.max(probs[0])
        class_ind = np.argmax(probs[0])

        return self.classes_names[class_ind], proba`

Comment: What is the error message in the fastapi environment?

Comment: the error is : Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric. I know that the problem in the types of labels but I don't know how I can fix it

Comment: You should use vector instead of string label. The classifier can not interpret the string as label. I recommend to convert "angry", "joy", etc into a vector [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0] and so on.

Comment: so the problem is that I worked with labels whose string format in the training model!! can I fix it in the deployment part or not!

Comment: Always transform categorical data to a numerical representation. Using onehot encoding or create dummies or label encoder.